# HttpClient Akka timeout settings

Tags: akka, httpclient, akka-http

I am trying to implement an HTTP client in my Akka app in order to consume a 3rd party API. 
What I am trying to configure are the timeout and the number of retries in case of failure. 
Is the below code the right approach to do it?

```
val timeoutSettings =
  ConnectionPoolSettings(config).withIdleTimeout(10 minutes)
  .withMaxConnections(3)

val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] =
  Http().singleRequest(
    HttpRequest(
      uri = "https://api.com"
    ),
    timeoutSettings
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not the right approach (for below I refer to the settings via .conf file rather than the programmatic approach, but that should correspond easily).

`idle-timeout` corresponds to the

> time after which an idle connection pool (without pending requests)
>   will automatically terminate itself

on the pool level, and on `akka.http.client` level to

> The time after which an idle connection will be automatically closed.

So you'd rather want the `connection-timeout` setting.

And for the retries its the `max-retries` setting.
The `max-connections` setting is only:

> The maximum number of parallel connections that a connection pool to a
>   single host endpoint is allowed to establish

See the [official documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/configuration.html#configuration)

Comment: There is no `connection-timeout` setting, not even in the documentation you linked. I'd also like to know how to modify the time the client spends waiting for the request to to return.